# Como importar para o código tabelas do banco com Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, entity-framework

No meu projeto, eu tenho apenas algumas entidades que não estão conectadas com o banco de dados, mas executo algumas procedures através do EF6.

Essas procs são apenas consultas que trazem dados cruzando informações de mais de uma tabela.

Agora eu quero inserir no mesmo projeto entidades e repositórios de tabelas que já existem no banco.

Como eu faço essa importação para código?

Comment: Não seria digitando?

Comment: Você pode fazer o mapeamento de sua tabelas do banco para a sua aplicação usando o [code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/hh972463.aspx)  ou atraves do [database first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: Tu usa EF pra persistir os dados ou só pra consultar VIEWS? E o que seria um repositório de tabela?

Comment: quando falo repositorio, seria a classe que faria o crud. vou usar EF pra persistir, fazer insert e consultar e mostrar na view. mas acho que vou criar tudo na mão mesmo. é que são muitas tabelas, achei que teria algo mais automatizado.

Comment: Tu pode pesquisar a sugestão do @MarconcilioSouza, com Code First ou DB First. Tu vai configurar a conexão e o EF gera pra ti as classes (tabelas) e o contexto...

Comment: @GuilhermeCamarotto, você pode criar um projeto a parte e fazer a importação do seu banco de dados para um repositório através do database first, e depois só ir copiando suas classes para seu projeto mesmo, o DataBase First gerar o arquivo .edmx que acredito que nem seja mais suportado no Entity FrameWork Code. Onde tudo agora seria baseado no Code First, Então aconselho já ir seguindo esse caminho.

Comment: @GuilhermeCamarotto, o Code first permite entre muitas coisas você criar um modelo mais amigável em relação a suas classes propriedades, pois muitos bancos de dados possuir estruturas muito feias.

Comment: Boa ideia @MarconcilioSouza, vou gerar em outro projeto e trazer para o meu só o que eu precisar. muito obrigado a todos pelas dicas.